# remove the first row from text using the excel

Tags: excel-2007, excel-2010

I have a data like below in text(.txt) format.

37|20050702030138|AR|ABC 2011-A|SOLD|2011|ENCUMBERED|ABC Auto Receivables

I dont want this values 37|, I have million of record like with the same issue.

Any idea, how to get rid of the unwanted data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

1. Open the text in excel
2. Use the Text to Table Option. If you want to remove the First value irrespective of length then select the "Delimiter" option. Else use fixed length option and select 2 characters.
3. You will get the First value / First 2 characters in a separate column.
4. Delete the first column in excel and save it as text.

Answer (score -1):

If the data is in `A2`, use this formula:

```
=Right(A2;len(A2)-3)
```